# Add the same image multiple times in the same location on word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a 100 page word document where each page has an image stretched to fit the page.
I need to add another image on top of all these images.

What can i do?

Comment: I think you can do that using 
**Send to background** option, although I haven't trieda as I work on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is in the background and it is the same image on every page, that is in the header or footer.

### You can go into the header and add another image to be in front.

You can place that wherever you want on the page (i.e. outside of the usual header/footer place).

Like the image itself, this will be faded when you are in the print view. Both will print at full strength on paper or pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If by "on top" do you mean in front, you can do so by using the watermark feature.

See the Microsoft articles:

- [Insert a picture watermark](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-picture-watermark-b48f5c1e-8b71-4aa3-b753-bc661760cd3a)
- [Adjust the placement of a watermark on the page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/adjust-the-placement-of-a-watermark-on-the-page-4665566a-3e5f-4705-a45e-b2afe)

Comment: i tried it, but the image is too light and i want all of the images to be on the top right

Comment: i could only make the watermarks appear in the center

Comment: See the article [Adjust the placement of a watermark on the page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/adjust-the-placement-of-a-watermark-on-the-page-4665566a-3e5f-4705-a45e-b2afe).